# Image animation issue when using jQuery .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, jquery-animate

I have an image animation problem that I need to fix. When the user hovers over the image, the image should increase in size. When the user moves out from the image, the image should return to its original size.

**Problem:** When the user moves over and out of the image very quickly, the image will expand and start distort itself, or change to a completely different size. It then continues animating while the mouse is not hovering over the image.

Here is a of the problem [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TbDrB/2/)

I encountered the same problem using `mouseover` and `mouseout` events in the `.on()` method. Also while chaining those events together in the `.on()` method

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<img id="foo" src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/297522main_image_1244_946-710.jpg"  alt="" title="" />
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#content').on("hover", '#foo', function (e) {
    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var $imgWidth = $img.width();
    var $imgHeight = $img.height();
    var $imgTop = $img.position().top;
    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
        $img.animate({
            top: $imgTop - 20,
            width: $imgWidth * 1.2,
            height: $imgHeight * 1.2
        }, 200);
    } else if (e.type == "mouseleave") {
        $img.animate({
            top: $imgTop + 20,
            width: $imgWidth / 1.2,
            height: $imgHeight / 1.2
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the width and the height of the image every time you hover over it, even while the image is animating, so the current values aren't really the ones you want.

Instead, store the original values and work on those:

```
jQuery('img').load(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    $this.data({
        'orig-width': $this.width(),
        'orig-height': $this.height(),
        'orig-top': $this.position().top
    });
});

jQuery('#content').on("hover", '#foo', function(e) {
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
        $this.stop().animate({
            top: $this.data('orig-top') - 20,
            width: $this.data('orig-width') * 1.2,
            height: $this.data('orig-height') * 1.2
        }, 200);
    } else if (e.type == "mouseleave") {
        $this.stop().animate({
            top: $this.data('orig-top'),
            width: $this.data('orig-width'),
            height: $this.data('orig-height')
        }, 200);
    }
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TbDrB/5/**

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain about storing that data? What if I have multiple images, using the same method?

Comment: For anyone else, yes this does work for multiple images. See fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/TbDrB/13/